# Why is this HTTP request being truncated?

Tags: http, iis-7.5

We've got a user who is getting an error on a page due to an HTTP request getting truncated. As far as we know, it is just the one user (though others might not have reported it). This is our main JS file that is included in all pages (all .NET pages, anyway) of the site. This seems to work for everybody else. The user is getting the error in both IE and Chrome.

The user’s browser reported this error:

> GET
>   http://fx.tourfactory.com/Bundles/Main.js?v=T5fF2ByrBfGogVek9EJ5vU_6zLwP4KyZ1erWAx6slWc1
>   net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH 1193174:1174

We ran Fiddler on the user’s machine and it gave this message:

> Content-Length mismatch: Response Header indicated 141,192 bytes, but
>   server sent 98,816 bytes.

Here is the Fiddler saz file with the request from the user’s machine and a similar request from my machine: [MainJsTruncated.saz](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/132991/MainJsTruncated.saz).

For some reason, the user’s machine is only getting the first part of the file then stops. This has been very consistent over the last couple weeks (that’s how long we’ve been trying to figure this out, off-and-on). We did pull some malware off the user’s machine, but that didn’t seem to help (somebody else is helping the user so I don't have any details on this).

I don’t think it’s the server since this is the only case we are aware of and we have thousands of regular users, but if it matters, we use IIS 7.5 running ASP.Net 4.5 and use the bundling feature to generate the Main.js file. The v=XXX is the way bundling manages browser caching when the file is updated; it is a hash of the file contents.

Any help in understanding what this could be would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to obtain a capture with a Network sniffer like Wireshark. Try to test with a different browser. Try also by booting and testing from a Linux live CD.